# get variable to url and navigate variable selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

can some one help me with my code

my page is about switching iframes

when i click on video 1 it has data-str="p9zdCra9gCE"

it will change only the end of src of iframe that is in class="load_video"

so i need to make this like this...
when ever i click on video 1 or video 2 i should get "p9zdCra9gCE" on url to make it something like page.php?p9zdCra9gCE

so when some one navigated to page.php?p9zdCra9gCE or page.php?0_MfMUN_FNM
then that data-str shoud be on iframe instead of switching by clicking video buttons. hope you understand guys , none helped me in this so far please guys.

here's my full code on plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/IPY3GF7Poyv1URrk84FH?p=preview

here's my php code

```
<?php

        $id = 1;
        foreach (glob('directory/*.php') as $file) {
            $file = str_replace('directory/', '', $file);
            $file = str_replace('.php', '', $file); ?>
            <div style="display:block;" class="video_link" data-str="<?php echo $file; ?>">Video <?php echo $id++ ?></div>
        <?php }

        ?>
```

here's my javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".frame_src").attr("data-src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p9zdCra9gCE");
        var t = "p9zdCra9gCE",
            e = $(".embed_code").attr("data-content");
        e = e.replace("[videoID]", t), $(".embed_code").html(e), $(".video_button").slideDown(), $(".video_link").click(function() {
            $(".reloadframe").show();
            var t = $(this).attr("data-str"),
                e = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + t + "",
                a = $(".embed_code").attr("data-content");
            a = a.replace("[videoID]", t), $(".embed_code").html(a), $(".frame_src").attr("src", e), clearInterval(interval), document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none", $(".frame_src").show()
        })
    });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `.click()` or `.on()` method documentation for jQuery. you are looking to use prevent the default click action (in this case you are stopping links from navigating to a new page) and replace it with updating an iframe with said link. The code will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //bind listener to elements the are used to update the iframe
    $('.updateFrame').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //stop normal click event
        $('.videoFrame').attr('src', $(this).data('src')); //update iframe src
    });
});
```

Comment: dear what you made this for? i don't see it getting that value from data-str to url to make it page.php?QrMOu4GU3uU or other value when i clicked on button. and when ever i go to page.php?QrMOu4GU3uU that video button must be switched already instead of clicking video button

Comment: First off, going to something like `page.php?QrMOu4GU3uU` isn't really a good way since you are not assigning any kind of solid `$_GET` array key. Also, all you have to do to assign the src attribute of the iframe when the page loads is to use the `$_GET` superglobal. My solution is for your question "How do I apply a click listener to switch my video in an iframe?" since that was what was asked.

Comment: ok but will that work without changing my codes? i mean my codes the way they work i want them like that and i want to make "click listener to switch my video in an iframe" ad you can make it, i will be really happy. you have full codes on plnkr as you see

Comment: i meant, if you can make it for me by adding $_GET array key what ever it needs to make it like that

Comment: Change page.php?xxxxxxxxx to something like page.php?video=xxxxxxxxx then add the src attribute to the frame_src iframe like this: `<?php echo (isset($_GET['video']) ? 'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $_GET['video'] . '"' : ''); ?>`

Comment: where do i add that dear? may i ask you to edit my php code on plnkr ?

Comment: @user099023 I updated my plnkr code from my link in the comments. If I solved your problem please mark it as solved.

Comment: no dear it is not working. it is not getting it in the url. my page link is domain.com/test/page1.php how you make it with code?

Comment: domain.com/test/page1.php?video=QrMOu4GU3uU using the code from my plnkr should initially load that video and the JS you initially wrote with overwrite that video in 10 seconds

Comment: no it doesn't work. there is 2 problems. first even if i navigate to domain.com/test/page1.php?video=0_MfMUN_FNM it will load the deault one that is " p9zdCra9gCE " when the countdown is 0 . and second problem is when i click on video button i don't get data-str at end of url to become like this domain.com/test/page1.php?video=0_MfMUN_FNM . and dear you think all that urls you see on my codes you think it is my page url ? no dear there is no page url at all in my codes. those are iframe url like embed links .

Comment: Updated my plnkr code for last time. The default video load is outside the scope of this question. The second problem i fixed in the new code.

Comment: yes it worked perfectly thank you so much. but loading default video ?

Comment: The loading default video after 10 seconds is done by your own JS. That is on you.

Comment: you don't know in JS to fix it for me ?

Comment: It is not my responsibility to fix your code. That is not what Stack Overflow is about. I answered the question you initially asked. If you have a different one, you can always as a new question.

Comment: thank you. i will ask about this as new question hope you answer it if you know. thanks again

Comment: here is my question link. you know what i am asking . if you can answer if i will be glad and if you can't it is ok just ignore it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926500/loading-video-from-url-array-key

Comment: can you please check and answer this question if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945525/hide-div-and-show-iframe-with-countdown-using-javascript